# Retrieving user's Birthday from google api calls

Tags: oauth, google-signin

**Problem** : I am facing difficulties in getting user's birthday from api calls and I am new to OAuth.

**Steps followed** : (Have followed all steps required for implementing login with google+)
1. Created an app.
2. Obtained app_id and secret_key.
3. Did not make use of SDK, implemented the process without SDK in php.
4. Obtained "CODE" by calling `accounts[dot]google[dot]com/o/oauth2/auth?`
5. Using the code from the URL parameters requested for access token by HTTPS POST method to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`, using CURL
6. When accessing the login page, user is asked for permissions to access the information such as email, profile, DOB etc., but I am not able to find a way to get that date of birth
7. I have tried access `www[dot]googleapis[dot]com/plus/v1/people/User_ID?key={THE_API_KEY}` . Still no luck

Please guide or suggest me on how to get the DOB. Also let me know if there is any other information I missed to share.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!
Farhan

Answer (score 4):

Well Well Ofcourse.. It has to be a security thing from google.

I got to know after I did a part of unit testing with different scenarios and missed out on a simple thing that google only responds with the b'day information if the user has allowed to in his profile settings.

all if the birth year is hidden, it will throw 0000 as year in the response of the HTTPS Post method.

If I am wrong in any of the information provided, Please do correct me.

Cheers!
Farhan.