# Retrieving date of birth and marital status with Google OAuth API

Tags: grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to retrieve date of birth and marital status via Google OAuth api. I get below mentioned info by setting the scopes as  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile & https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email . Request URL is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

```
{
 "id": "my_id",
 "email": "test@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "name": "full_name",
 "given_name": "first_name",
 "family_name": "last_name",
 "link": "https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxx",
 "picture": "https://xxxxxxxxx/photo.jpg",
 "gender": "male",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

I have birthday and marital status set in my profile, but I'm unable to get this info. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set scope to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

and request url is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

**NOTE:-** Relationship Status and Birthday only available to you **if user set them public**.

Have a look to this [google api explorer](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get).

I have tried this using [grails oauth plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/oauth) and make my birthday and relationship status public it gives me

```
[birthday:1988-04-02, ..., relationshipStatus:single, ...]
```

**EDIT.................................................................................**

```
Q. New problem with email, I can't get it after changes
```

You can set multiple scopes like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

and make two requests one for birthday and relationship status

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

and another for email

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for help, but I'm just wonder, when I hide year of birth in my profile I receive 0000 instead of it. It's bit a strange, cause actually I don't need month and day of birth without year.

Comment: Have a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646474/retrieving-users-birthday-from-google-api-calls

Comment: Yes, but it's a little stupid of google. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: New problem with email, I can't get it after changes.