# Retrieving date of birth from Google OAuth API in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, google-oauth, owin

I have added following scopes to access data from user

```
#region Google
 var googleAuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google_AppID"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google_AppSecret"]
        };
        googleAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
        googleAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
googleAuthenticationOptions.Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                //context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("birthday", context.User.GetValue("birthday").ToString()));
                string claimType;
                bool bAddClaim = false;
                foreach (var claim in context.User)
                {

                    claimType = string.Empty;
                    bAddClaim = false;
                    switch (claim.Key)
                    {
                        case "given_name":
                            claimType = "FirstName";
                            bAddClaim = true;
                            break;
                        case "family_name":
                            claimType = "LastName";
                            bAddClaim = true;
                            break;
                        case "gender":
                            claimType = "gender";
                            bAddClaim = true;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (bAddClaim)
                    {
                        string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                        if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Google"));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

While debugging at **context.user** in side foreach loop by putting breakpoint
I am getting following information

```
{
"sub": "101111724115925537597",
"name": "Alok Nath",
"given_name": "Alok",
"family_name": "Nath",
"profile": "https://plus.google.com/101111724115925537597",
"picture":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/
          photo.jpg",
"email": "aloknathbabuji786@gmail.com",
"email_verified": true,
"gender": "male",
"locale": "en"
}
```

So even after adding the "profile" scope, I don't get birthday as part of return value. I have made sure that profile has Birthday visibility set to public i.e. it is visible to all. Is there any specific scope or specific settings I need to do in order to retrieve Birthday from **Google**?

Or is there any way to resolve this problem please post the solution

Comment: Have you tried adding the nuget package **Google.Apis.OAuth2.v2 Client Library** to your project? This also gives you an enum for your scope so instead of using strings, you can just say: `Scope = { Oauth2Service.Scope.UserinfoProfile, Oauth2Service.Scope.UserinfoEmail }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login in order to get date of birth suggested by this stackoverflow user:

[Retrieving date of birth and marital status with Google OAuth API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612357/retrieving-date-of-birth-and-marital-status-with-google-oauth-api)

More information can also be found here:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#plus.login