# How to retrieve user DOB and Gender in Google Sign iOS in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am using google sign In in one of my app. I cant find a way to retrieve Date of Birth and Gender. Can anybody please help. Here is my code using swift -

```
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: NSError!) {
            if (error == nil) {

                // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
                let userId = user.userID                 
                let idToken = user.authentication.idToken              
                let name = user.profile.name
                let email = user.profile.email

                print(userId)
                print(idToken)
                print(email)
                print(name)
      } else {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access what a user has set to public. If the user doesn't want this information public then you cant have the information.

Just because I authenticate your application doesn't mean that I want you to for example to see my address or in this case my gender. So I don't set them public you cant see them.

Comment: I have set my birthday as public but i couldn't find a way to retrieve it. Lets say "user.profile.name" will give me my name but how about DOB and gender?

Comment: You can fallow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612357/retrieving-date-of-birth-and-marital-status-with-google-oauth-api

Answer (score -1):

self.databaseref = Database.database().reference()
            self.databaseref.child("user_profiles")
            self.databaseref.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

```
            let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if(snapshot == nil)
            {
                self.databaseref.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).child("name").setValue(user?.displayName)
                self.databaseref.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).child("profilephoto").setValue(user?.photoURL)
                self.databaseref.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).child("phonenumber").setValue(user?.phoneNumber)
                self.databaseref.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).child("email").setValue(user?.email)
            }
            print("snapshot:",user?.displayName)
            print("snapshot:",user?.photoURL)
            print("snapshot:",user?.phoneNumber)
            print("snapshot:",user?.email)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Fetch the Google signin details for email,  profile and display name

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.