# How to retrieve user data when Signed in using Google SignIN?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I want to get user's gender and birthdate after he signed in through Google into my app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407330/how-to-retrieve-user-dob-and-gender-in-google-sign-ios-in-swift

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/ try this

Answer (score 0):

Google not provide the information like gender and birthday 
when you sign in with google you only get email, id , photo(if user use) , and given name and access token to verify user

Comment: is there a way using people API?